# Can I remove grey border below tabs in JavaFX Modena using CSS?

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

Basically, I'm trying to remove the grey line below the tabs so it appears flat (lol, ignore bad Spanish translations - I'm currently working on fixing the bundles):
[image]

I've tried `-fx-padding: 0;` and `-fx-border-width: 0;` on various tab-related components.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the background insets of the tab header region.

You can solve this by putting this in your stylesheet:

```
.tab-pane:top > .tab-header-area > .tab-header-background {
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 0 0, 0;
}
```

Comment: The background insets value didn't work for me but I set it to 100% and it seems to have pretty much done the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @user3530525 I've updated my answer, missed the other two states. So now it should work as expected.